# reading from file in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I'm trying to read some integers from a file. The program compiles with no errors but it doesn't print the integers.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
if(argc != 2){
    printf("Use %s file_name", argv[0]);
}
else{
    char file_name[255];
    int df,n=0,v[1000],tmp,i;
    strcpy(file_name,argv[1]);
    df=open(file_name,O_RDONLY);
    while(read(df,tmp,sizeof(n))>0){
        v[n++] = tmp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
}
return 0;}
```

new code :

```
 int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
if(argc != 2){
printf("Use %s file_name", argv[0]);
}
else{
char file_name[255];
int df,n=0,v[1000],tmp,i;
strcpy(file_name,argv[1]);
if ((df=open(file_name,O_RDONLY) ) < 0) {
perror("Cannot open output file\n"); exit(1);
}
while( n != 1000 && ( read(df,&v[n++],sizeof(*v)) > 0) ){}
for(i=0; i!=n; i++){
printf("%c ",(char)v[i]);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

even before it only showed 2 of those bit patterns instead of 3 even though i have 3 characters in my file

Comment: One thing you need to do when asking questions here is to be clear on the one hand that this is a homework assignment, and on the other hand make sure you list all the info, rules you have to follow for the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read takes a pointer to buffer as it's second arg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
if(argc != 2){
    printf("Use %s file_name", argv[0]);
}
else{
    char file_name[255];
    int df,n=0,v[1000],tmp,i;
    strcpy(file_name,argv[1]);
    if ((df=open(file_name,O_RDONLY) ) < 0) {
    perror("Cannot open output file\n"); exit(1);
    }
    while( n != 1000 && ( read(df,&v[n++],sizeof(*v)) > 0) ){}
    for(i=0; i!=n; i++){
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm actually surprised your program didn't segfault - you're using an uninitialized int as a pointer value.  You need to check if the file was succesfully opened.  You also need to make sure you don't overflow your buffer, so you need to check n on each iteration.  Also, there's no need to use a temp variable, you can write directly into your buffer.

Comment: ok now it seems to work but it's not printing what's in the file. it's printing some random big numbers

Comment: @Adrian Are your "numbers" in *text*? if not, are they in the same bit-depth and endian format in both the *writer* of the file and the *reader* of the file?

Comment: Using the value as a pointer is undefined behaviour, so there's no saying what may happen.

Comment: i just made a new file and wrote "8 2 9" in it ( without the quotes )

Comment: Those are characters, not integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time! But it's till printing out just big numbers. should i try to read the stuff into a char[] ?

Comment: What you'll get when you read is an integer containing the bit pattern of the integer values of those characters.  http://www.asciitable.com/  If you hit return at the end of the line, you'll have a file containing exactly 4 bytes: 0x38 0x32 0x39 0x10  The last char being the newline character.  The bit pattern those four contiguous bytes represent will be some large positive number.

Comment: Oh ... That makes sense now. So I casted them to char and now it prints only 8 9. why doesn't it also print the 2 ?

Comment: Upload your new code so I can see it.  You can add it at the bottom of your OP.

Comment: How is the file organized?  Space separated chars on the same line?  Or one number per line?  If You want to read numbers written in a text file, and not a binary file, then the solution given by WhozCraig is probably a better way to go.

Comment: yep space separated chars on the same line. i know that's a better way to go but i have to use these functions (homework ..) If I open the file in a hex editor it shows those three bytes (38 32 39) with spaces in between and 0A at the end

Comment: Depending on what OS you're on ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline ) you'll have either a one or two byte newline, so you've got either 2 or 3 bytes per line.  But every time you read an int you're reading 4 bytes, since that's the size of an int.  Can you figure it out from here?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I'm reading byte by byte until I encounter a space. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

read takes a void* so you need to pass the address of the variable you want to use to store the values

try this

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Use %s file_name", argv[0]);
    }
    else{
        char file_name[255];
        int df,n=0,v[1000],tmp,i;
        strcpy(file_name,argv[1]);
        df=open(file_name,O_RDONLY);
        while(read(df,&tmp,sizeof(n))>0){
            v[n++] = tmp;
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d ",v[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I just changed temp by &temp